# how to insert data into databse Useing Ajax Jquery,php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have tried many ways to build a  commenting system for my website  with php jquery,ajax but problem with inserting comments in data base  what is the problem with my code

**Html**

```
 <div id="comments" class="cmt">
    <form method="post"  > 
             <textarea class="textinput"id="comment" rows="5" name="comments" placeholder="Comment Here......"></textarea><br>
                <button type="button" id="comq"name="compost" class="butn2" >post comment</button>
    </form> 
 </div>
```

**Jquery and ajax**

```
      $(document).ready(function()
     {
       $("#comq").click(function() {
           var comment=$("#comment").val();
           $.ajax({
            cache:false,
            type:"post",
            url:"pnf.php",
            data:{comments:comment},
            success:function(data)
            {
             $('.cmt').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Php (pnf.php)**

```
 if(isset($_POST["compost"])){                
      $comment=$_POST['comments'];        
   {
   $reslt_user= mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tbl_users,`queries` where id='".$_SESSION['id']."' AND  qid= '".$qid."' ");
    $row_lat_lng= mysqli_fetch_array($reslt_user);
    $stmt = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO comments set uid='".$_SESSION['id']."',comments='".$comment."',reply='".$reply."' ,
qid= '".$qid."' ");

    }                             
    if($stmt)
   {
        echo "hello world";
   }  

}
```

Comment: @RajkumarR what proper code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
HTML

 <div id="comments" class="cmt">
   <textarea class="textinput" id="comment" rows="5" name="comments" placeholder="Comment Here......"></textarea><br>
   <button type="button" id="comq"name="compost" class="butn2" >post comment</button>
 </div>
```

For PHP:

```
 if(isset($_POST["comments"])){

   $comment = $_POST['comments'];

   $reslt_user= mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tbl_users,`queries` where id='".$_SESSION['id']."' AND  qid= '".$qid."' ");
   $row_lat_lng= mysqli_fetch_array($reslt_user);
   $stmt = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO comments set 
    uid='".$_SESSION['id']."',comments='".$comment."',reply='".$reply."' ,
    qid= '".$qid."' ");


  if($stmt)
  {
     echo "hello world";
  }
}
```

Comment: What you say whith out form how

Comment: @Mystartup2016 For ajax, form is not required. Your jQuery is ok.

Comment: You added `if(isset($_POST["compost"])){`, in this case the key is not passed wit name *compost*, hence the condition becomes false. Secondly, there were extra pairs of opening and closing brackets.

Comment: But button name compost

Comment: @Mystartup2016 Button type is `button` and not submit. In ajax, whatever you pass in data, delivers at the php end.

Comment: @Mystartup2016 Glad to help.

Comment: @Mystartup2016 can connect on linkedin. Search by my name. Above written spellings are wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in type:

```
     if(isset($_POST["compost"])){

      $comment=$_POST['comments'];
```

I mean `$_POST["compost"]` and `$_POST["compost"]` are different variables

Comment: in JQuery AJAX call you are posting only one variable: comments

Answer (score 0):

first just isset the $_POST Comment to check if you have you comment value

```
if(isset($_POST["comments"])){

  $comment=$_POST['comments'];

  $reslt_user= mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tbl_users,`queries` where id='".$_SESSION['id']."' AND  qid= '".$qid."' ");
  $row_lat_lng= mysqli_fetch_array($reslt_user);
  $stmt = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO comments set uid='".$_SESSION['id']."',comments='".$comment."',reply='".$reply."' ,qid= '".$qid."' ");

  if($stmt)
  {
      return true;
  }
}
```

second you can id to your form to reset after the ajax call success

```
<form id="myForm"> // add ID to your form

success:function(data){
     if(data == true){
        $('#myForm')[0].reset(); //to reset your form after success 
        $('.cmt').html(data);
     } else{
          //do the error msg
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing working code snippets.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="comments" class="cmt">
    <form method="post" onsubmit="submitComment(); return false;">
        <textarea class="textinput" id="comment" rows="5" name="comments" placeholder="Comment Here......"></textarea><br>
        <button type="submit" id="comq"name="compost" class="butn2" >post comment</button>
    </form>
    <p id="message" ></p>
</div>

<script>

    function submitComment() {

        var comment = $("#comment").val();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "post",
            url: "pnf.php",
            data:{
                comment:comment
            },
            success:function(data) {
                $('#message').html(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and PHP script

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST["comment"])) {

  $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['comment']);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`comment`) VALUES ('".$comment."')";

  $res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

  if($res) {
    echo "success";
  } else {
    echo "error";
  }

}
```